# how to create a hidden element as well as inline-block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div and I want to be both inline-block and display none, but I have to choose one of them.

My HTML:

```
.like_user_wrapper{
    margin-top:20px;
    padding:5px; 
    height:55px;
    box-shadow:1px 1px 10px #f0f0f0;
    background:white;
    display:inline-block;
    display:none;
}
```

It's not a good idea to have the div just hide using JavaScript

Comment: Is `visibility: hidden;` an option? What do you exactly want?

Comment: What is the point? if it's `display: none`, it simply will NOT count for any sizing/positioning calculations. If you want it count for sizing/positioning but still be invisible, then make it `visibility: hidden`, as Hashem pointed out.

Comment: use `visibility:hidden` instead of `display:none`. for your use case, it would work out fine

Comment: Else `opacity:0;` or `position:relative;left:-9999px;`

Comment: @kesong Tse you could use an id and class attribute to apply two display  styles or as @hashem quolami suggested you could use a `visibility:hidden` because `display:none` and `visibility:hidden` do the same function

Comment: Setting it to be both `inline-block` and `display:none` is just nonsense.

Comment: @MarcB, when the user hover some element, this div would show , and because this is a container div, I don't it to the size according to its parent's width, and I want to resize this div according its inner element 's width, so I need inline-block, however, I need to hide it by default

Comment: then use visibility instead.

Comment: @MarcB but it would leave a lot of margin , this is the point

Comment: You realize you're asking for something's logically impossible? "Make something that's visible yet invisible, doesn't have any size, but still has size"?

Comment: @MarcB, May be I have not choice but to use some javascirpt, but thanks.  You tone is funny

Comment: Actually, my tone is annoyed. You give us essentially NOTHING in the way of useful information, and no reasons WHY you need things like this. If the only way we can answer this is to play twenty questions and EVENTUALLY get some useful information, then this question doesn't belong here.

Comment: @KesongTse Just posted an answer you might want to consider using that.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `visibility: hidden;`

```
#like_user_wrapper{
    margin-top:20px;
    padding:5px; 
    height:55px;
    box-shadow:1px 1px 10px #f0f0f0;
    background:white;
    display:inline-block;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

<sup>Note this is using a custom ID (`#`...) , not a class (`.`...)</sup>

If you want is to become visible at some point, you can use this JavaScript property with that ID:

```
document.getElementById('like_user_wrapper').style.visibility='visible';
```

This can be included in a `onmouseover=""`, or a javascript function etc, so it appears when you want it to. This can be implemented in html [like this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/rep55zb0tverewq/b.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#like_user_wrapper {
    margin-top:20px;
    padding:5px; 
    height:55px;
    box-shadow:1px 1px 10px #f0f0f0;
    background:white;
    display:inline-block;
    visibility: hidden;
}
#hover {
    width: 80px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body style="background-color:blue;">
<div id="like_user_wrapper">Like User Wrapper</div>
<br><br>
<div id="hover" onmouseover="document.getElementById('like_user_wrapper').style.visibility='visible';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('like_user_wrapper').style.visibility='hidden';">Hover over me</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Help page on the visibility CSS property [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp)

N.B. In most browsers, by default a DIV has the display property `block`, so you might not need `inline-block` - you could just wrap it in a `<div>` with that property anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to hide and show the element using jQuery, to display it back avoid using `jQuery.show()`.

Instead do `$('.like_user_wrapper').css({'display': 'inline-block'});` to display the element.

On the other hand, to hide it is ok to just do `$('.like_user_wrapper').hide();`

And remove the `display: inline-block` from your css.