# dynamically create a bootstrap-4 row and append divs to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a little gallery for myself, in which I can upload pictures. What I have been trying to achieve so far has been the following: I want to upload multiple pictures, but each picture should be set in a `<div class="card">` (and then I create a `<div class="card-body">` and append it to the card. and within the `<div class="card-body"` the picture should be appended) and each card should have the class `col-md-4`. These cards are made dynamically. However whenever I try to do it without a row, it'll append each `div` underneath each other, since it's default `display` is `block`. Doing it with a `<div class="row">` around it, hasn't gotten me any further, since it will create a row everytime it loops through the `FileList` object, therefore also placing the `<div class="card">` underneath each other 
again.

So to sum it up in bullet points:

***The problem:***

whenever I loop through the pictures and dynamically create my `card` classes, I either end up creating for each `card` a new row, or I take out the row, but end up having the `div` aligned underneath each other, because of the default `display`.

***What I have tried so far:***

I tried using 2 display types (I already use display hidden for the divs so I can scroll them down) and then I also tried adding a `display: inline-block` to it, but according to this post: [how to create a hidden element as well as inline-block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21960846/how-to-create-a-hidden-element-as-well-as-inline-block)
that's considered, and I quote: *Setting it to be both inline-block and display:none is just nonsense.*
It does the trick for me, but the scroll effect dissapears once I implement it, so it's not entirely what I am looking for.

The reason I am looking for a row around it, is so I can place the `div` next to each other (for every 3 pictures I 'review'), with the intention of making all the `div` the same height, because right now they differ from height, based on the picture within the `div`.

***What I am trying to achieve:***

- Create a row dynamically and append (dynamically) `div` to it with each having `col-md-4` as class.

***How my code looks at the moment I am writing this:***

```
for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++) {

        let reader = new FileReader();

        //I am trying to append this row once, let it be filled with 3 div 
         (let's say I upload 3 pictures so I need 3 divs), each having col-md-4 and place it next to each other. When I upload a 4th picture, a new row should be appended with,
         which in turn will be able to hold up to 3 divs if needed (if I upload another 3 pictures)

        let row = document.createElement('div');
        row.setAttribute('class', 'row');

        let card = document.createElement('div');
            card.setAttribute('class', 'card col-md-4 imagePreviewCard');

        let header = document.createElement('div');
            header.setAttribute('class', 'card-header imagePreviewHeader');


        let namePicture = document.createElement('input');
            namePicture.setAttribute('type', 'text');
            namePicture.setAttribute('name', 'namePicture');
            namePicture.setAttribute('id', 'namePicture');
            namePicture.setAttribute('class', 'col-md-10');
            namePicture.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Title pic');


        let deleteButton = document.createElement('a');
            deleteButton.setAttribute('class', 'btn btn-danger fa fa-trash col-md-2');

        $(deleteButton).on('click', function() {
            $(this).closest('.card').slideUp();

            setTimeout(function(){ 
                $(this).closest('.card').remove();
            }, 1000);

        });             

        $(header).append(namePicture, deleteButton);

        let body = document.createElement('div');
        body.setAttribute('class', 'card-body imagePreviewBody');

        $('#imgUploadBody').append($(card).append(header, body));

            setTimeout(function(){ 
                $(card).slideDown();
            }, 600);

        let img = new Image();
            img.setAttribute('class', 'resizeForcer');

        reader.onload = function(e) {
            img.src = e.target.result;
            $(body).append(img);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```js
let imalges = ["url1","url2","url3","url4","url5"];
let div='';
let j = 3;
for(var i = 0; i < imalges.length; i++ ){
  
  if(i % 3 === 0 || i == 0 ) div +=  "<div class='row'>";
    div +=  "<div class='col-md-4'>" + imalges[i] + "</div>";
    
  if( j == i || i === 2 || (imalges.length-1) === i )  {
    j += 3
    div +=  "</div>";
  
  }
}


document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = div
console.log(div)
```

```css
.row{
  
  display:block;
  
  
}
.col-md-4{
  
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: You could inject arbitrary HTML/JS into the document if you have control over the values in the `imalges` array.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to avoid creating a row for each card, move it outside of the loop. Create the row before the loop begins.

As for the .row class, here is what you may need to know:

Bootstrap utilizes flex-box for the row and its elements. See [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
.row {
    display: flex;
}
```

However, you are not limited to using the rows. You can use your own container and apply the the `display: flex` on it.

Alternatively, you can also make the cards align next to each by setting the cards to display as `inline-block` elements. See [display|CSS tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/) for more information.

```css
.card {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The following snippet will demonstrate both scenarios. Give it a try

```js
$(function () {
    let flexBoxContainer = $('<div>').addClass('flexbox-container').prependTo(document.body);
    createCardsFor(flexBoxContainer);
    let normalContainer = $('<div>').addClass('normal-container').prependTo(document.body);
    createCardsFor(normalContainer);
})

function createCardsFor($container) {
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        let card = $('<div>').addClass('card').css({
            'margin': '10px',
            'box-shadow': '0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0, .2)'
        }).appendTo($container);
        let cardHeader = $('<div>').addClass('card-header').appendTo(card);
        let cardImage = $('<img>').attr({
            alt: "alt",
            src: "https://via.placeholder.com/50"
        }).appendTo(cardHeader);
        let deleteButton = $('<button>').addClass('btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger').text('Delete').on('click', deleteButtonClick).appendTo(cardHeader);
        let cardBody = $('<div>').addClass('card-body').appendTo(card);
        let bodyTitle = $('<h5>').text('Title').appendTo(cardBody);
        let bodyText = $('<p>').text('Lorem Ipsum Dolor...').appendTo(cardBody);
    }
}

function deleteButtonClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

```css
        .flexbox-container {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }

        .normal-container .card {
            display: inline-block;
        }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

P.S.: You've got an organized code which is a very good practice in my opinion. Keep it up that way!

**Update**

And there is an example of creating a row dynamically and append columns to it:

```js
$(function () {
  let row = $('<div>').addClass('row').prependTo(document.body);
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        let col = $('<div>').addClass('col-md4').appendTo(row);
        createCardsFor(col);
    }
})
function createCardsFor($container) {
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        let card = $('<div>').addClass('card').css({
            'margin': '10px',
            'box-shadow': '0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0, .2)'
        }).appendTo($container);
        let cardHeader = $('<div>').addClass('card-header').appendTo(card);
        let cardImage = $('<img>').attr({
            alt: "alt",
            src: "https://via.placeholder.com/50"
        }).appendTo(cardHeader);
        let deleteButton = $('<button>').addClass('btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger').text('Delete').on('click', deleteButtonClick).appendTo(cardHeader);
        let cardBody = $('<div>').addClass('card-body').appendTo(card);
        let bodyTitle = $('<h5>').text('Title').appendTo(cardBody);
        let bodyText = $('<p>').text('Lorem Ipsum Dolor...').appendTo(cardBody);
    }
}

function deleteButtonClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```